# Java reflection, get class string array

Tags: java, reflection

the code is

```
Field field = st.class.getField("g_"+selectedGroup);
```

`st` is my class, and `g_+"selectedgroup"` is in the st class as String array

how to get that string array?

I need something: `String sa[]= field.getStringArray[];` but only `getInt`, `getBoolean` there is :(

how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Field field = ST.class.getField("g_"+selectedGroup);
String[] sa = (String[])field.get(stInstance);
```

Where `stInstance` is an instance of `ST` class.

Answer (score 1):

You just use [`get`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
field.get(instance);
```

If it's a static field, `instance` can be null (or really anything).

Comment: You are right, I made a very silly mistake. Now corrected. +1